# Custom ListView Filtering and Bring back old item in the list

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am developing app that has listview. I have used custom Adapter and added filtering option.It's working fine when I put text in the ssearchBox But the problem is when I start to erase the text from searchBox it does not bring back the item..It stays there.

This is my code...Please help.

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer{

    private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private ArrayList<String> mCurrentList;
    private Context mContext;
    HolderFilter holderFilter;

    public SimpleAdapter(ArrayList<String> mCurrentList, Context mContext) {
        super();
        this.mCurrentList = mCurrentList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mCurrentList != null)
            return mCurrentList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        if (mCurrentList != null)
            return mCurrentList.get(position);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int p = position;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_row_layout, null);

        try {
            TextView textRow = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            textRow.setText(getItem(position));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
            if (section == 0) {
                // For numeric section
                for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                    String text = null;
                    try {
                        text = mCurrentList.get(j);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if (text == null)
                        return 0;
                    else if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(0)).toLowerCase().equals(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(k)).toString().toLowerCase()))
                        return j;
                }
            } else {
                String artist = null;
                try {
                    artist = mCurrentList.get(j);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if (artist == null)
                    return 0;
                else if (String.valueOf(artist.charAt(0)).toLowerCase().equals(String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(section)).toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
            sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
        return sections;
    }
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (holderFilter == null){
            holderFilter = new HolderFilter();
        }
        return holderFilter;
    }
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private class HolderFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values = mCurrentList;
                results.count = mCurrentList.size();
            }else {
                List<String> nHolderList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String h : mCurrentList) {
                    if (h.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nHolderList.add(h);
                }
                results.values = nHolderList;
                results.count = nHolderList.size();
            }
            return results;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                mCurrentList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are filtering the items, you are resetting back your original array which contained all the items. You need to preserve it, by having two arrays:

- One will contain all the items - This will be uses as the bases of your filter.
- Second will contain filtered items - This will be actually used in your adapter. If there are no results, you simple set this to first array.

See example below:

```
/*
 * Author: Madhur Ahuja
 * Copyright (c) 2014.
 */

package in.co.madhur.vocabbuilder.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import in.co.madhur.vocabbuilder.R;
import in.co.madhur.vocabbuilder.model.Word;

/**
 * Created by madhur on 22-Jun-14.
 */
public class WordTokenAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{
    private List<Word> words, originalWords;
    private Context context;

    public WordTokenAdapter(List<Word> words, Context context)
    {
        this.setWords(words);
        this.context = context;

        originalWords = new ArrayList<Word>();

        for (Word word : words)
        {
            originalWords.add(word);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return getWords().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return getWords().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return getWords().get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Word word= (Word) getItem(position);
        View view;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.word_token_item, parent, false);
            holder.word = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word);
            holder.ratingBar=(RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            view.setTag(holder);


        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        holder.word.setText(word.getName());
        holder.ratingBar.setRating((float)word.getRating()/2);

        return view;
    }

    public List<Word> getWords()
    {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(List<Word> words)
    {
        this.words = words;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return new Filter()
        {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


                List<Word> filteredWords;

                // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
                {
                    filteredWords = new ArrayList<Word>();

                    for (Word word : originalWords)
                    {
                        if (word.getName().startsWith((String) constraint))
                        {
                            filteredWords.add(word);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    filteredWords = originalWords;
                }


                synchronized (this)
                {
                    results.count = filteredWords.size();
                    results.values = filteredWords;
                }

                return results;


            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {

                List<Word> filteredWords = (List<Word>) results.values;

                words = filteredWords;

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
    }


    private static class ViewHolder
    {

        TextView word;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to android.Can You tell me where add code in my snippet?